# How do I catch sdk changes in my unittests when mocking properties

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using the voidspace [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) library in a set of unittests for an api client I am developing. I've just had a problem where the API changed (and an attribute on the sdk got renamed) and the mocked version of the sdk that I use in the tests didnt pick this up (I'd like them to fail when I try mocking properties & methods on that dont exist on the mocked sdk). I'm rewriting the tests to use `spec_set` but I cant seem to get them to work.

If I have a class `MyItemClass` with a property `name` and a method `run` how do I mock this in such a way that if a property or method gets renamed in the sdk I pick it up in the unittest.

`MyItemClass` is on the lines of:

```
class MyItemClass:
  ...

  @property
  def name(self):
    return self._details.name  

  def run(self):
    ... do something ...
    return result
```

Currently I am trying:

```
mock_item = mock.MagicMock(spec_set=sdk.MyItemClass)
type(mock_item).name = mock.PropertyMock(return_value="Item title")       
mock_item.run = mock.MagicMock(return_value=foobar)
```

but this doesnt pick up a renaming in the `MyItemClass` of the property `name` to `item_name`, it just carries on mocking (and so the tests pass).

Equally, this code (which the docs say you shouldnt do due to the way PropertyMocks are stored):

```
mock_item = mock.MagicMock(spec_set=sdk.MyItemClass)
mock_item.name = mock.PropertyMock(return_value="Item title")       
mock_item.run = mock.MagicMock(return_value=foobar)
```

appears to pick up the rename (and fail when `name` is set), but when the naming is fixed, the mocks dont appear to work in the same way as before (tests start failing because the properties arent returning what tests expect, presumably because of the dropping of the `type()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like its a bug or missing feature in the python mock library. I've raised the same question as an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/mock/issues/detail?id=218) and my original workaround is the best answer until this feature is added:

I work around it with the following code:

```
def add_property(mock_object, property_name, property_value) :                  
    prop = mock.PropertyMock(return_value=property_value)                       
    setattr(type(mock_object), property_name, prop)                             

    # this catches sdk changes if spec_set is used with the MagicMock as        
    # it will fail if you assign the property to an non-existant attribute                                                           
    mock_object.attach_mock(prop, property_name)

mock_item = mock.MagicMock(spec_set=sdk.MyItemClass)
add_property(mock_item, 'name', "Item title")
```

as `add_property` will fail in the attach_mock if the property `name` is removed or renamed, which then breaks the unittests as desired.